# how to disable a button dynamically

Tags: objective-c

How to disable a button after entering a particular letter in a textfield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the text field's value to one of your object's properties and ensure to check the "updates continuously" box in Interface Builder. For this example, the property will be called `theText`. Then, bind the enabled state of the button using a key-value path of say `containsLetterA`, then in your object put the method

```
- (BOOL) containsLetterA
{
    NSRange rangeOfLetterA = [[self theText] rangeOfString:@"A"];
    return rangeOfLetterA.location != NSNotFound;
}
```

Then, also in your object, add the class method:

```
+ (NSSet *) keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForContainsLetterA
{
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"theText", nil];
}
```